# How do draft item security affect indexing for search?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, crawling, versioning, content-approval

**Some info:**

In my SharePoint 2010 environment I have set the "Draft Item Security" to "Only users who can edit items". The search service account have Full Read permissions and should be able to index all items in the document library during it's full crawl.

So the problems is that when I search the documents whose version is not a major version and have special permissions on it is not visible.

**The question:**

So the question might should be: How can i crawl **ALL** documents on a site? What permissions-level should the service account have to index the documents?

Full-Read won't do. When you think about it, the crawl account Full read, and the "Draft Item Security" setting says "Only Users who can **EDIT**". So must we change to contribute/design permissions level?

**Some more info:**

It's not because of the permissions on the user that I'm doing the search with, I can go to the location of the document and see it.

Basically the only permissions-group/level who can't see the document is "Read".

So I assumed that the search service account can't see it.(I don't have the possibility to log in on this account). I've tested to change the accounts permissions on the site but no luck.

I'm aware that this question might be a replica of this: [How can I get draft documents in a document library to be crawled by search?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42022/how-can-i-get-draft-documents-in-a-document-library-to-be-crawled-by-search)
But by reading the answers it did not help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So while writing the question i answered my own question.

"Draft Item Security" setting says "Only Users who can EDIT". So we must change to the permission-level from Full Read to Full Control, not the cleanest way to solve this, but it works.

Have any input please let me know :)

Comment: You are correct, though, generally, giving the crawl account full control is considered a bad practice for exactly this reason. It will cause unpublished items to appear in the search results. In fact you are the first person I have found that this is a desired outcome. Can you explain the reason?

Comment: Are you asking me about why I want to crawl all the content?

Comment: No, why do you want to circumvent draft item security? By design, SharePoint does not crawl draft items. Unpublished items are not intended to be in search results. Why change that?

Comment: Well, just a task, not my decision to take. :) Whats the downside to crawling draft items? More to crawl, longer crawl time/slower system? (I noticed that users that have low permissions can still find the location of draft items, but ofc only see the items in the location that they were meant to see. So that might be a big no-no)

Comment: Generally it is considered a bad idea to show draft items. Like I said, you are the first to try to make it happen on purpose. It has to do with the security trimming of the search results and the presentation of the search results. Users get lower quality search experience.

Comment: BTW, if your users are struggling to find items left in draft mode, there are reports like Content and Structure that resolve this, it's just not optimal for Search.